# Designing an algorithm that searches for the kth largest element between two AVL trees

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, complexity-theory, avl-tree

This was a challenge question given in lecture last week and I've been mulling over it since. We were asked to create an algorithm that searches between two AVL trees for the kth largest element. Each node in the two trees contains two pieces of information: its integer value and the number of children it has in its subtree including itself (so a leaf would have 1 child). The complexity of the algorithm cannot be worse than O((logn)^2).

I've thought of comparing each node in one tree to every node in the other tree but that would be O(n) complexity which is too slow.

Comment: I'm guessing that `n` is the number of nodes in both trees combined?

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, let design a function that for given upper bound *b* determines how many elements in the AVL-tree are less when *b*:

```
count(node, b)
    if node.key < b:
        return node.left.size + 1 + count(node.right, b)
    else
        return count(node.left, b)
```

There are only one recursive call in each branch, and the depth of the node is increased on each call. So the complexity of this function is O(log(n)).

Now we can build the required function using `count`:

```
kth(k, node1, tree2)
     left = node1.left.size + count(tree2, node1.key)
     if k < left:
        return kth(k, node.left, node2.right
     else if k == left:
         return max(upperBound(tree2, node1.key), upperBound(node1.left, node1.key))
     else if k == left + 1:
         return node1.key
     else
         return kth(k - node1.left.size - 1, tree2)
```

For this function `node1` also increased in each recursive call, so we have *O(log n)* calls, each requiring *O(log n)* time due to call of the `count` function. The total running time is *O(log² n)* as required.

To complete this solution it is needed to design function `upperBound` that should return the maximum key in the subtree. This could be done easily in *o(log n)* time.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the `k-th` element is in the first tree. We can binary search over it's position in the tree. For a fixed position `p`, we can find the `p-th` element in the tree in `O(log n)` time (by starting from the root and going left of right depending on the size of the left subtree).

Now we need to find the number of elements in the second tree that are smaller than this element. We can do it in `O(log n)` time by starting from the root and going to the left or to the right depending on the value in the current node (and adding the size of the left subtree to the answer when we go right).

When we know the number of elements smaller than the given one in the second tree (let's call this number `s`), we know that its position in the union of the trees is exactly `s + p`.

This algorithms runs in `O(log^2 n)` time.

If the `k`-th element is not in the first tree, it must be in the second tree. So we repeat this procedure for the other tree to get the answer in general case.